# Circumvent Boostrap-Table from rendering 100+ rows slowly

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, bootstrap-table

I'm rendering a list of state objects (with Spring and Thymeleaf) on my view page:

```
<table id="state-table" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" data-pagination-v-align="top" data-search="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-sortable="true">ID</th>
          <th data-sortable="true">Descrizione</th>
          <th>Azioni</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr th:each="s : ${state}">
        <td><span th:text="${s.id}"></span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${s.descrizione}"></span></td>
      </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The table contains about 150 elements, but when the page is rendering I see for less than a second an ugly page (is the plugin trying to paginate the result) and I would like to avoid it.

I have already tried adding a timeout as workaround:

```
$(function() {
        $("#state-table").bootstrapTable("showLoading");

        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#state-table").bootstrapTable("hideLoading");
        }, 1000);
});
```

but with this code, when the page renders, I see a strange html page at beginning, then I see the loading message, and finally the table with all elements loaded.

I think I have to intervene before (or while) the table is created but I don't know how. What would I need to do so that the table is rendered correctly without the user noticing the ugly "un-bootstraped" table?

Answer (score 0):

Try To use Pagination instead of showing all your entries.
Hope it help you : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-pagination